# Sending sms using php {"error":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}

Tags: php, sms, clickatell

I trying to send sms message to users using php language .
I using curl to send this message but I have this error

```
{"error":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}
```

I used Clickatell as sms api .
this is my code

```
echo $url= 'https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/sendapiKey=ordnzDdGdRhqdnjdf3ZmzYA==&to=904234234&content=your+password+is+BhSTV';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: try to use `GET` instead of `POST`, as `GET`, like `HEAD`, cannot be disallowed

Comment: better to use their php lib [here](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/php-library/)

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/clickatell/clickatell-otp-example/blob/master/src/otp.php) - I also recommend doing a GET as @Kaddath mentioned, your telling Curl its a POST with this line `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);`

Comment: thank you very much that worked perfect .

Comment: Glad to see it helped!  Feel free to mark it as helpful - since I didnt "answer" your question as an answer - have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL is incorrect. Try this:
`https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=ordnzDdGdRhqdnj...`